# Unknown faucet type spins freely

Tags: repair, faucet

[image: faucet]

I've unscrewed seemingly everything that can be except the pipes. Spinning the rod with a wrench just spins it freely except for a slight bump at the angle where it originally "broke". The numbers on top in raised brass letters are 016p a55e, which doesn't return any useful search results. It's a single handle, temperature adjustment only faucet. Trying to pull the center part out like I've seen elsewhere doesn't budge, even though there was a pin whose purpose was seemingly to hold it in.

The other parts removed:

[image: parts]

Comment: put the handle back on and pull straight out ... the clip that you removed kept it from coming out on its own

Comment: I already mentioned, if you try to pull it out (I used a vice grips, but I tried again just now with the handle) it doesn't move at all. There must be something else I haven't removed (the white plastic part maybe?)

Comment: wasn't there a flat clip holding the white part into the valve body? ... the stem and the white part should pull out as one piece

Comment: Added a photo of the parts removed. The clip at the end did indeed look like it was holding everything in, but removing it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an early generation Moen control. These cartridges can get calcium buildup making them very difficult to pull out. Try prying with an awl tapped into the white plastic vertical boss the stem comes through. Then turn the cartridge to break loose the deposits and allow the cartridge to be removed. If you can try needle nose pliers to turn the plastic  Note turning does not unscrew the cartridge, only loosen it so it can be pulled out.